# How to make Unix 'top' display current network bandwidth or disk activity?

Tags: linux, unix

I know I can use the iostat command to view disk activity, but I would prefer one utility that shows everything in one window, kind of like Perfmon on Windows or ActivityMonitor on the Mac.
Can top show these things?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Also for network usage; [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/) does by address, [nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/) does by process.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) and [nmon](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-analyze_aix/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, nmon is a nice utility that runs on almost all platforms. You can log nmon entries to a file for post-processing. There is a [nmon Excel spreadsheet analyzer](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-nmon_analyser/) that reads the nmon output file and charts everything for you. There is also java and python libraries you can build apps on nmon outputs.
[image]